# Dash App deployment on Linux virtual machine and user concurrency problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, deployment, plotly-dash

I'm a Data Science student finishing the thesis project and a Dash rookie.
I've created for my internship some analysis tools that I will have to share with many users inside the company, and by checking all of the possibilities to deploy the tools I decided to use Dash to let my co-workers work with the dashboard by using the browser. The dashboard is already functioning on my laptop, but I'm currently experiencing headhaches to understand how could I share it by using a Linux VM that my company provides me.
It's the first time that I have do deploy something i have created and i'm in trouble with it.

Basically, the dashboard does create some matplotlib plots based on some user input (thanks to dropdowns) and makes it available to the user by returning an encoded image of the plot (why? it was the easiest way for a Dash rookie). This image is saved by some "backend" functions in a local directory every time the function is called (by the `callback function` that i share later in the question), so I suppose that once I deploy the dashboard on the VM an awful event could happen: every time a *n+1* user asks to the dashboard to create a plot, the functions that create the plot could overwrite the plot figure that a *n* user is trying to obtain.
I don't know if this concurrency problem will actually happen when I'll deploy the dashboard onto the VM, but i would like to hear any possible solution to avoid this: my spider-senses are telling me that this will happen.

Just to make it clear before someone asks me, I decided to avoid using plotly because the functions necessary to create the matplotlib plots were already available and cannot be changed. So, as a Dash rookie, I found this escamotage to plot the data using images, but now I'm kinda regretting it. I'd like to hear any other possible solution as I didn't find anything helpful on the Dash documentation.

Considering the code on which the dashboard relies, there are some "backend" functions (`function1`, `function2`, ...) that I use to create different plot types based on different inputs. The plot is saved in the folder, and the following `update_spec` callback function calls the "backend" function and pick the result from the folder, sending it to the dashboard Img component to plot it as an image.
The callback function (simplified) is something like:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id = "matplotlib-plot", component_property = "src"),
    [Input(component_id = "gran_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "proj_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "pj_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "cc_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "name_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "surname_sel", component_property = "value"),
    Input(component_id = "category_sel", component_property = "value")]
)
def update_spec(gran, proj, pj, ccost, name, surname, category):
    if condition1:
        if condition2:
            if condition-a:
                fig = function1(params)
            elif condition-b:
                if sub-condition:
                    fig = function2(params)
        else:
            if condition-c:
                if sub-condition:
                    fig = function3(params)
            elif condition:
                if sub-condition:
                    fig = function4(params)
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("dir\\test.png", 'rb').read())
        return'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
    else:
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open("dir\\white.png", 'rb').read())
        return'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())
```

Each "backend" function (`function1`, `function2`, ...) creates the plot and saves it in a folder as something like `....\dir\plot.png` as can be seen in the last few rows.

-How could I prevent users from overwriting images to each other?
-How could I separate the users scopes and letting them see only the plot-image that they have asked, by preventing them to see the other ones images?
-Does Dash already take care of my problem?
-Is containerization of the dashboard a good solution? Like a dashboard container for each user that connects to the VM?
-Is there any reliable guide to study and follow to deploy the dashboard?

I tried to read the Dash documentation, but all the informations about deploying to VMs seem to persuade me to purchase the Dash Enterprise service. My company won't allow this.

Sorry about my bad english and my lack of experience/knowledge in this field, any suggest sould help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, this is quite an long story with lots of details and you seem to have a lot of questions. It would be easier for people to answer your questions if you'd split it up in multiple more focussed questions.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaAngnoe, i'll split it up soon! Hope it will be easier to understand after. I'm new to SO, so I have to understand how to ask and how to answer yet. Thanks for the suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach is to assign an identifier for each user, let's call it `session_id`. You can then use this identifier in path(s), i.e. `....\dir\plot.png` would be `....\dir\[session_id]\plot.png`.

One simple way to assign a `session_id` is to add a hidden `Div` element on the page, which is populated with a uuid on page load, i.e. something like

```
import uuid
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

# Create example app.
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id="session_id", style={"display": "none"}),
    html.Button("Show session id", id="btn"),
    html.Div(id="log")
], id="page")


@app.callback(Output("session_id", "children"), [Input("page", "children")])
def set_session_id(_):
    return str(uuid.uuid4())


@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")], [State("session_id", "children")])
def show_session_id(_, session_id):
    return session_id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

In terms of deployment, i agree that a containerized solution would be suitable. However, note that each instance of the container is not only able to server one user; it could serve tens, hundreds or thousands of users depending on app complexity and server resources. This is a bit off topic as compared to the other question though, so it would probably be better if you asked another question for this part.

Comment: I'll try it this approach as soon as possible, my colleagues are working on the Server right now and I can't tell you if this will solve the problem. Nevertheless, is a pretty cool way to solve it. Regarding the containerization part, I'll make a new question. Thanks.